# Proper way to override properties and methods in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

What is the proper way to override methods using [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) in Vue.js?  I know that you're able to mock inheritance using mixins, but let's say that you want to extend some props but not completely override the entire prop value.

For instance I have a baseCell, but I also need to have components that will be similar but function differently for `<td>`s and `<th>`s, so I create two additional components that use the baseCell as the mixin.

```
var baseCell = {
  ...
  props: {
    ...
    initWrapper: {
      type: String,
      default: 'td'
    },
    ...
  },
  methods: {..}
};
```

In the components setting the props as such will completely override all the values.

```
Vue.component('tableHeader', {
  mixins: [baseCell],
  props: {
    initWrapper: {
      default: 'th'
    }
  }
}
```

I've come up with a solution of merging the properties but it seems sort of hacky, and I'm not sure if there is a better solution.

```
Vue.component('tableHeader', {
  mixins: [baseCell],
  props: Object.assign({}, baseCell.props, {
    initWrapper: {
      default: 'th'
    }
  })
});
```

With this, I retain the baseCell props, but some defined ones in the object passed.

Comment: The documentation https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Option-Merging clearly states that that the component will take precendence on merges.  As a result, your solution seems quite reasonable.

Comment: @DavidL Thank you for looking at the question.  I had seen that part of the docs but only glanced over it.  Your comment made me dig a little deeper into the source and as a result I found this issue that addresses the question of merging data and props... https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2897 It looks like the current solution is to do it as I currently am.

Comment: Agreed, based on that issue it definitely would seem like you picked the right solution.  Happy to help :)

Comment: What about using `extends` instead of `mixins`? I can still pass the original props.

Answer (score 1):

In Vue > 2.2 you can use custom option merge strategies to achieve what you want. Note that the strategy applies to all mixins.

An example can be found here in the docu:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Custom-Option-Merge-Strategies